# xcode project conversion to iOSOpenDev

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak, cydia

I would like to convert a 'regular' xcode project to deploy using [`iOSOpenDev`](http://www.iosopendev.com/). From what I can tell, when a new project is created using the iOSOpenDev templates, it has the following in the build settings:

```
EXCLUDED_RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATH_SUBDIRECTORIES = *.nib *.lproj *.gch (*) .DS_Store CVS .svn .git .hg *.xcodeproj *.xcode *.pbproj *.pbxproj
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(iOSOpenDevPath)/include/**
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 5.0
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = $(iOSOpenDevPath)/lib/**
SDKROOT = iphoneos
iOSOpenDevInstallOnProfiling = YES
iOSOpenDevPath = /opt/iOSOpenDev
```

Is it sufficient to add these to another project in order to get the iOSOpenDev install on profiling build to happen, or do I need to set something else up?

I'm not really interested in building a 'jailbroken' specific type of application, but would like to deploy to a jailbroken iphone without having a paid ios developer account.

Note openssh is already installed through cydia (with a non-default passwd) and iosod has been configured with `iosod sshkey -h [device-hostname-or-ipaddress]`

Comment: did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: I did not make much progress after I posted this question nope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**2012-12-14:**

I've written a wiki article about this. See https://github.com/kokoabim/iOSOpenDev/wiki/Convert-to-iOSOpenDev-Project.

**Previous Answer:**

1. Modify existing target's Xcode build settings with those defined in `/opt/iOSOpenDev/templates/Base.xctemplate/TemplateInfo.plist` and `/opt/iOSOpenDev/templates/Debian Package.xctemplate/TemplateInfo.plist`.
2. Add a *run script* build phase (must be last in order) to existing target that executes `/opt/iOSOpenDev/bin/iosod --xcbp`.
3. Create the Debian package control file under the existing target's folder as `(target's directory)/Package/DEBIAN/control`.
4. Perform a **Build For Profiling** (Cmd-Shift-I).