# Convert regular xcode application project to iOSOpenDev

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, jailbreak

I'm new to jailbroken dev. I have a regular xcode application project. Now I need to convert it, or create a new application project using iOSOpenDev for jailbroken dev. I found the same question:

[xcode project conversion to iOSOpenDev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358317/xcode-project-conversion-to-iosopendev)

But I have no idea what to do with the first step. Do I need to add some settings or change some values of existed settings? Pleas give some more details.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the first step, I did some tryings and it worked out. The following steps is just the same as kokoabim said:

1.change the install path to `/Applications`; add iOSOpenDev's include,lib,framework folder path to `Framework Search Paths`,delete `iphonesimulator` from `Supported Platforms` in `Build Settings`, `Header Search Paths`, `Library Search Paths`(I'm not sure if it's necessary);

1. Add a run script build phase (must be last in order) to existing target that executes `/opt/iOSOpenDev/bin/iosod --xcbp`.

3.Create the Debian package control file under the existing target's folder as `(target's directory)/Package/DEBIAN/control`.

4.Perform a Build For Profiling (Cmd-Shift-I).

Comment: Should a have a provisioning profile from my iOS Developer Account to build app for jailbroken iPhones?