# How to create normal app(without Tweak) in iosopendev

Tags: ios, ios6, jailbreak, cydia

i am trying to create a cocoa touch project with a single view in iosopendev but may be somewhere i am doing it wrong as the icon of the project is not visible in application list of  my iPhone.Below are the step i have taken to crete a project

1. selcted cocoa touch project in iosopendev
2. added the IP address of my device in iosopendevdevice
3. created new target added Xcode "single view" project and selected "don't code sign" everywhere needed.
4. selected build for profile

The project builds without any error and i can see the project name in Cydia but don't know how to open it and see the view of my app
please let me know where i am going wrong.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358317/xcode-project-conversion-to-iosopendev) post to create app and getting this error
"target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.application', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform" when the device is selected in schema.

Comment: regarding the error it was because of Xcode file corruption i reinstalled the Xcode. now i am not getting any error.but the app still does not show in application list.